# ImageView shown only in the last row of listview

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview

I have an activity with a listview that contains couple of EditText and image view.
When User is sign up his data (name,phone,profile image etc...) stored in firebase.
I want the imageview which located in listview row to show the profile image of each user.
I have the image download Uri and I use picaso to set the profile image to the image view.

**The problem is: the profile image shown only in the last row of the listview..**

This is how I set the profile image to the ImageView:

```
public void getProfileImage() {
    mDatabase.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = ds.getValue(User.class);
                    if (!user.getUserImage().equals("default"))
                        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(user.getUserImage()).into(profileImage);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Hope someone can figure out what is the problem.
Thank you.

**Edit:**
This is the listview adapter:

```
public class mainScreenAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TrempData>  {

    private TextView  name ,timestamp ,uid, from,to,date,time,myextra ;
    private ImageButton phoneBtn;
    private ImageView timeline, profileImage;
    private int layoutResource;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;



    public mainScreenAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, ArrayList<TrempData> list) {
        super(context, layoutResource, list);
        this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;


        if (view == null) {
            final LayoutInflater Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = Inflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);

        }

        final TrempData data = getItem(position);
        //data.setPos(position);
        //int[] androidColors = getContext().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidcolors);
        //int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];


        if (data != null) {
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myname);
            phoneBtn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.myphone);
            //myphonestr = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.myphonestr);
            timestamp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mytimestamp);
            uid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myuid);
            timeline = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.timeline);
            profileImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.mycar);
            date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mydate);
            time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mytime);
            from = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myfrom);
            to = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myto);
            myextra = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myextra);
            name.setText(data.get_name());
            //name.setTextColor(randomAndroidColor);
            //myphonestr.setText(data.get_phone());
            timestamp.setText(data.get_timestamp());
            uid.setText(data.get_uid());
            date.setText(data.get_date());
            time.setText(data.get_time());
            to.setText(data.get_to());
            from.setText(data.get_from());
            uid.setText(data.get_uid());
            myextra.setText(data.get_extras());

            phoneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + data.get_phone()));
                    getContext().startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(uid.getText())){

                phoneBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //car.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(255,164,30));

            }
            else{

                phoneBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //car.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(176,176,176));

            }
        }
        getProfileImage();
        return view;

    }

    public void getProfileImage() {
        mDatabase.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = ds.getValue(User.class);
                    if (!user.getUserImage().equals("default"))
                        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(user.getUserImage()).into(profileImage);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Update:**
I did what @Danilo de Oliveira suggest me to do and it works but now I have new problem. The profile image is the same in each row although the download image Uri is different in each user in firebase

Comment: Can you provide where you get a reference of profileImage. I think the problematic code block is where you get a reference of the related row.

Comment: Are the other views the same for each rows? What about name for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you call getProfileImage() every time getView() runs. This is what is actually happening:

For the row 1:
    loop through all dataSnapshot.getChildren()
         load image to profileImage

For the row 2:
    loop through all dataSnapshot.getChildren()
         load image to profileImage

For the row 3:
    loop through all dataSnapshot.getChildren()
         load image to profileImage

...

So you are always loading N photos to the profileImage, ending up with the last image is shown each row.

This should be the flow:

```
1. Load all your data from firebase.
2. Store them in an ArrayList<User> mUsers
3. listView.setAdapter(yourAdapter)
4. In getView()
    4a. Get your user by mUsers.get(position)
    4b. Get your imageview by view.findViewById(...)
    4c. Load your image here.
```

This should be working.

Also I think you should examine how list view and list adapters work.

Answer (score 0):

"profileImage" is a class variable and you get image uri through async request, so when the image uri is loaded you have the last reference to ImageView.
You could try...

```
// The key type Integer is an example
private HashMap<Integer, ImageView> imageMap = new HashMap<>();
private int trempDataListSize;

public mainScreenAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, ArrayList<TrempData> list) {
    super(context, layoutResource, list);
    this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    trempDataListSize = list.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    TrempData data = getItem(position);
    ...
    ImageView profileImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mycar);
    ...
    // Store the userId as key and imageView as value
    imageMap.put(data.getUserId(), profileImage);
    ...
    // Execute getProfileImage() once
    if (position = trempDataListSize - 1) {
        getProfileImage();
    }
}

public void getProfileImage() {
    mDatabase.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = ds.getValue(User.class);

                // Check if imageMap has the key (userId)
                if (!user.getUserImage().equals("default")
                      && imageMap.containsKey(user.getId()))

                    // Get the value (imageView) by userId
                    Picasso.with(getContext())
                        .load(user.getUserImage())
                        .into(imageMap.get(user.getId()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It works but I have new problem now. I update the question for the new problem.

Comment: Can you perform firebase query before the adapter be set?

Comment: Its like the image that attached to the imageview is allways of the last user in firebase

Comment: I mean if you could execute `mDatabase.child("Users").addValueEventListener(...)` before instantiate mainScreenAdapter and store image uri in a variable inside `TrempData` for each user.
Then inside `onDataChange()` and after the foreach you instantiate `new mainScreenAdapter(...)`

Comment: I got it. Does `TrempData` have a reference to `User` (id or something like that)?

Comment: Yes. In both of them I stored the user id

Comment: Can you share with me what you think is the problem @Danilo de Oliveira ?

Comment: For sure is `mDatabase.child("Users").addValueEventListener(...)`, which is executed every time a view is created and iterates every user.

Comment: You must have a way to get ImageView instance binded to a specific user.

Comment: You could just pass imageView and userId as parameters in getProfileImage(), check if userId (from parameter) matches to userId (from user) and assign imageUri to the imageView. But it consumes much processor, because it performs a iteration every time a view is created.